# Three.js使用中にWebGLがブロックされましたと警告が出て描画が止まってしまいます。

Tags: three.js

ブラウザはChromeでThree.jsを使用して開発を行っています。

球体を描し、そしてその球体に画像を貼り付けるということをやっています。
そして貼り付ける画像を切替えるという事をやってみました。
オブジェクトはそのままにtextureのみ差し替えています。
ここまでは問題なく動作しています。

しかし何度か画像の切替えを行っていると一定の数値で「WebGLがブロックされましたと」とChromeが警告を表示し真っ暗になってしまいます。
再読み込みを行うとまた正しく動作するのですがやはり画像の切替えを行っていると一定回数で「WebGLがブロックされましたと」と出てしまいます。

この時Chromeのコンソールに CONTEXT_LOST_WEBGL という警告が出力されています。

調べてもいまいち原因が分からず躓いてしまっています。

どなたか原因が分かる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 調査を続けていたところIEでは問題なく動作し続けました。いったい何が原因なのでしょう、、、、

Comment: 本家SO回答"[How do we handle webgl context lost event in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350350/)"や”記事[Handling Lost Context in WebGL](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/HandlingContextLost)"が参考になるかと思います。